# Wordpress text editor field required in form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

Please help me to fix the below text editor in form with conditional required function via JavaScript or any HTML stuff.

I am using wp editor field in front end to upload resume for job seeker. But I want this field required (*) so form will not be submitted until this form blank.

```
$editor_id = 'resume_content';    
$editor_css = '

<style>
    .wp-editor-container{
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
    }

    .wp-switch-editor,
    .tmce-active .switch-tmce, .html-active .switch-html{
        height:25px;
    }
</style>';

wp_editor( $default['resume_content'], $editor_id, array( 'editor_class' => 'form-control', 'media_buttons' => false, 'editor_css' => $editor_css,  ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use.

```
<?php wp_editor( $listing->post_content, 'listingeditor', $settings = array('textarea_name' => post_content) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter function:

```
add_filter("the_editor", "add_required");

function add_required($editor){

  $editor =  str_replace( '<textarea', '<textarea required="required"', $editor );
  return $editor;

}
```

Comment: Thank you Kamil. I am not good too much. Can you sent em complete code with id as mention in my question. It will be good for me..Thanks once again

Comment: thanks, so need to add this function before or after my code in same file or use through function.php

Comment: Place it somewhere in your function.php

Comment: I've tested it. It works. I can't submit  form while this field is blank. There is obviously no red (*) mark because I didn't add it, but when I check this textarea on firebug there is: `<textarea required="required" class="wp-editor-area" rows="20" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="test" id="test"></textarea>` So filter function was executed correctly.